# Maping and changing states in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mapping

I have an object like this below:

```
const initialState = {
  filters: {
    categories: [
      { text: "a", checked: true },
      { text: "b", checked: false },
      { text: "c", checked: false },
    ],
    brands: [
      { text: "d", checked: false },
      { text: "e", checked: true },
      { text: "f", checked: false },
    ],
    types: [
      { text: "g", checked: false },
      { text: "h", checked: true },
    ],
  },
};
```

and I need to change all of the checked fields oto 'false' on click. I am using redux and it's my initial state. Under is my function, but it doesn't work correctly. It is saying that "state.filters.map is not a function".

```
const filtersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RESET_ALL_STATES":
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: {
          ...state.filters,
          ...state.filters.map((filter) =>
            filter.map((option) =>
              option.checked === true ? { ...option, checked: false } : option
            )
          ),
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Because `state.filters` is an object

Comment: Your arrays are `state.filters.categories`, `state.filters.brands` and `state.filters.types`, not `state.filters`.

Comment: oh right, my stupid mistake, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution used `Object.entries` to iterate through all the key/value pairs inside the `filter` object to reset each array's element values to `checked: false`.

```js
const state={filters:{categories:[{text:"a",checked:!0},{text:"b",checked:!1},{text:"c",checked:!1}],brands:[{text:"d",checked:!1},{text:"e",checked:!0},{text:"f",checked:!1}],types:[{text:"g",checked:!1},{text:"h",checked:!0}]}};

const resetFilters = Object.entries(state.filters).reduce(
  (acc, [key, arr]) => {
    acc[key] = arr.map((el) => ({ ...el, checked: false }));
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(resetFilters);
```

In the context of your reducer, this might look like:

```js
const filtersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "RESET_ALL_STATES":
      return {
        ...state,
        filters: Object.entries(state.filters).reduce(
          (acc, [key, arr]) => {
            acc[key] = arr.map((el) => ({ ...el, checked: false }));
            return acc;
          },
          {}
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `filters: Object.entries(state.filters)...` instead of `filters: Object.entries(initialState.filters)...`?

Comment: @secan correct, thank you for catching that typo!

Comment: You're welcome but... you amended the wrong snippet ;)

Comment: Thanks again, it's early heh